# How to insert a record on next selected date if count of a date is full

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where I maintain working days in a week like 2nd and 4th day and number of records it can accept is 10 records per working day

```
usercode    DaysofWeek        NumberOfRecords
0623PO54    2                 10
0623PO54    4                 10
```

On insertion I have application date example `01-09-2017(dd/mm/yyyy)` which is Friday.

Now I have to insert this record in closest working day from `01-09-2017` which is `05-09-2017` as it is 2nd working day. After inserting 10 records next records should be insert on 4th working day which is `07-09-2017`.

I don't know how to get closest date from application date and insert record on it.

Comment: You need to improve your question further. Edit the text, add sample data and then how it needs to be changed depending on your input parameters.

Comment: Please show what you expect the output to be in full.

Comment: Do you have a calendar table ? Please show its definition.

Comment: Working days vary by country and even company.  Example: some UK businesses close between Christmas and New Year, others don't.  For this reason you'll need to maintain a table of dates that flags which are/are not a working day.  @Serg is right.  If you have a calendar table use it, if not research the subject.

Comment: i am using dot net calendar and in my database i am storing only day of week like 2nd or 4th which means  Tuesday and Thursday

Comment: Are you inserting records 1 at a time or you try to insert N rows at a time and only 20 of them should be accepted?

Comment: 1 record at a time

Comment: And if you want to insert the 21st record with 01-09-2017 you should insert nothing or it should insert with 12-09-2017?

Comment: it should insert on next weeks working day means 12-09-2017

Comment: This means, the date it should put in depends not only on the input date but on the latest date presented in you table and on the number of rows in the table with the latest date?

Comment: yes that's what i want

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to exclude holidays than use a master table for Ex. CalenderMastr of dates which have holidays flag and day of week like Monday=2. and as you mansion that you are maintaining working days in a table for ex. workdaymaster. Now make a select query to get next date from CalenderMastr from current date and day of week stored in workdaymaster. now on output date check if in your transaction table count is smaller or not if count is small insert new record or if not than move to next date using while loop in your query. hope you can understand what i am trying to say.

Comment: hi, i am getting what you trying to say. it will more help full if you post some example like query